# Limiting SQL Injection when query is almost entirely configurable

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, mariadb, sql-injection

I have a requirement to perform a scheduled dump of a SQL query from a web application. Initially it was an entire table (only the table name was configurable), but then the addition of a configurable WHERE clause was raised, along with a subset of columns.

The configurable options now required are:

- columns
- table name
- where clause

At this point, it might as well just be the entire query, right?!

I know that SQLi can be mitigated somewhat by `java.sql.PreparedStatement`, but as far as I can tell, that relies on knowing the columns and datatypes at compile time.

The configurable items will **not** be exposed to end users. They will sit in a properties file within `WEB-INF/classes`, so the user's I am defending from here are sysadmins that are not as good as they think they are.

Am I being over cautious here?

If nothing else, can `java.sql.PreparedStatement` prevent multiple queries from being executed if, say, the WHERE clause was `Robert'); DROP TABLE students;--`?

Comment: parameterizing it should prevent that

Comment: You don't seem to fully understand how a **PreparedStatement** works (which is fine). Parameters are evaluated as parameters so *Drop table* or any other sql statement will not be executed as such. It's just a (part of) a parameter, not a statement at all. You're pretty safe as far as SQL injection is concerned.

Comment: Also, you can't parameterize a table name. It's possible to do this using a *Statement* (e.g. "select * from " + tableName )  where tableName is a variable.

Comment: This also depends on the DBMS **and** JDBC driver you are using. Not all drivers actually allow to run more then one statement through a single `execute()` call. And some DBMS offer built-in functions to at least minimize the risk when using concatenated SQL queries

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name currently MariaDB, but the software I am extending also supports MS SQLServer and Oracle.

Comment: With the Oracle driver the `drop tables` attack won't work as it will simply reject running more then one statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A prepared statement will not handle this for you. With a prepared statement you can only safely add *parameters* to your query, not table names, column names or entire where clauses.

Especially the latter makes it virtually impossible to prevent injection if there are no constraints whatsoever. Column and table name parameters could be checked against a list of valid values either statically defined or dynamically based on you database structure. You could do some basic regex checking on the where parameter, but that will only really help against obvious SQL injection. 
With the flexiblity you intend to offer in the form of SELECT  FROM  WHERE  you could have queries like this:

```
SELECT mycolumn FROM mytable WHERE id = 1 AND 'username' in (SELECT username FROM users)
```

You could look at something like JOOQ to offer safe dynamic query building  while still being able to constrain the things your users are allowed to query for. 
Constraining your users in one way or another is key here. Not doing that means you have to worry not just about SQL injection, but also about performance issues for instance. Provide them with a visual (drag-and-drop) query builder for instance.

Comment: Accepted this answer because it answers the question clearly and provided decent suggestions. Other answers missed the point of the question which was that this will NOT be exposed to end users in a UI. It will be in a properties file editable only by sysadmins.

Answer (score 0):

"It all depends".

If you have an application where users can type in the where clause as free text, then yes, they can construct SQL Injection attacks. They can also grind your server to a halt by selecting huge cartesian joins.

You could create a visual query builder - use the schema metadata to show a list of tables, and once the table is selected the columns, and for each column the valid comparisons. You can then construct the query as a parameterized query, and limit the human input to the comparison values, which you can in turn use as parameters.

It's a lot of work, though, and in most production systems of any scale, letting users run this kind of query is usually not particularly useful...

Comment: Can you provide an example of how users can construct an sql injection attack (a *PreparedStatement* assumed)?

Comment: It's not *regular* end users that will be able to define the query, only users that have the ability to edit a properties file on the application server itself e.g. sysadmins. I have discovered, though, that sysadmins aren't all awesome. Some probably shouldn't be allowed to touch a keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's insecure to allow users to execute arbitrary queries. This is the kind of thing you'd see at Equifax. You don't want to allow it.

Prepared statements don't help make SQL expressions safe. Using parameters in prepared statements help make *values* safe. You can use a parameter only in the place where you would normally put a constant value, like a number, a quoted string, or a quoted date.

The easiest solution would be to NOT allow arbitrary queries or expressions on demand.

Instead, allow users to submit their custom query for review.

The query is reviewed **by a human being,** who may authorize the stored query to be run by the user (or other users). If you think you can develop some kind of automatic validator, be my guest, but IMHO that's bound to be a lot more work than just having a qualified database administrator review it.

Subsequently, the user is allowed to run the stored query on demand, but only by its id.

Here's another alternative idea: users who want to run custom queries can apply to get a **replica** of the database, to host on their own computer. They will get a dump of the subset of data they are authorized to view. Then if they run queries that trash the data, or melt their computer, that's their business.